# Actions are not connected anymore after 6 buttons in KYCircleMenu

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am working on a `KYCircleMenu`. The library only includes 6 buttons, but I want to have 7 buttons. I managed to add one more to the screen. The only problem is that it didn't get an action.

Here is the [library](https://github.com/Kjuly/KYCircleMenu)

Here is how I make the buttons.

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= buttonCount_; ++i) {
    UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonOriginFrame_];
    [button setOpaque:NO];
    [button setTag:i];
    imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:self.buttonImageNameFormat, button.tag];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(runButtonActions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.menu addSubview:button];
  }
```

The `runButtonActions` is only added to the first 6 buttons. My buttonCount_ is 7. And only the 7th button does nothing.

Any help ?

Comment: set a NSLog or breakpoint at the start of `runButtonActions:`, check if it really isn't executed

Comment: No didn't print anything when I push on the seventh button. On all the other buttons it prints my log.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your button is outside of the touchable area.

I have tried to reproduce your code (yes, I was bored), and when I set the 7th button in the demo project like this:

```
[self _setButtonWithTag:7 origin:CGPointMake(centerBallMenuHalfSize + triangleB - buttonRadius + 20, centerBallMenuHalfSize + triangleA - buttonRadius+20)];
```

it works fine, but when I set it just bellow the other buttons like this:

```
[self _setButtonWithTag:7 origin:CGPointMake(centerBallMenuHalfSize - buttonRadius, centerBallMenuHalfSize + triangleHypotenuse + buttonRadius + 10)];
```

the action does not work.

However, when I add 200 pixels to the frame height (aprox. Line 153)

```
CGRect centerMenuFrame = CGRectMake((viewWidth - menuSize_) / 2, (viewHeight - menuSize_) / 2, menuSize_, menuSize_+200);
```

it works in that case too. Just figure out the right frame for your button positions, set it, and everything should work as expected.

PS: Once you have finished consider proposing an expansion for KYCircleMenu or creating a branch, it is a very nice control and your code might help to make it better.